# IDEA projects, clarification needed

Tags: intellij-idea

Using `InteliJ IDEA`,  I am trying to set up **multiple** projects to run as part of the same IDE.

When import it (`File->New Project->From Maven`) only the latest imported project shows up.

How can i get multiple projects to appear?

[image]

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html. You can add multiple modules instead.

Comment: Ok, but can setting be then different for each module (JDK version etc)

Comment: Also, does it mean that i should have parent project of some kind, or should i just have a collection of modules?

Comment: It's the closest thing you can get as IntelliJ IDEA has no `Workspace` concept.

Comment: Each module can have different JDK configuration, you can set dependencies between modules. Just think that `Project` is a `Workspace` and `Module` is a `Project`. It's what you can find in the FAQ.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17902/discussion-between-jam-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can [find in the FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html), IntelliJ IDEA `project` maps to Eclipse `workspace` and `module` maps to Eclipse `project`.

Create one IDEA project and then add multiple modules to it. Modules can have different JDK and language level settings.